# trying to let users add new topics to page, but page only returns the bullet points, NO topic names. works fine in admin backend but defeats purpose

Tags: python, django

Working thru my 1st python/Django project. Need to let users add new topics to a blog page, but page only returns the bullet points, NO topic names. Works fine on admin back end which of course defeats purpose of user entry"

`````
    {% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

    {% block content %}
      <p>Add a new topic:</p>
       <form action="{% url 'blog:new_topic' %}" method='post'>
         {% csrf_token %}
         {{ form.as_p }}
         <button name='submit'>add topic</button>
       </form>

    {% endblock content %}
    ```

    ```
    {% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

    {% block content %}

      <p>BlogPosts</p>

      <ul>
        {% for topic in blogposts %}
           <li>
              <a href="{% url 'blog:topic' topic.id %}">{{ topic }}</a>
           </li>
        {% empty %}
           <li>Nothing's yet been posted</li>
        {% endfor %}
       </ul>

       <a href="{% url 'blog:new_topic' %}">Add a new topic:</a>

    {% endblock content %}
    ````
    {% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

    {% block content %}

      <p>Topic: {{ topic }}</p>

      <p>Entries:</p>

      <ul>
      {% for entry in entries %}
        <li>
          <p>{{ entry.date_added|date:'M d, Y H:i' }}</p>
          <p>{{ entry.text|linebreaks }}</p>
        </li>
      {% empty %}
        <li>
          There are no entries for this post yet.
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
      </ul>

    {% endblock content %}
    ````
    Here are the views: 
        from django.shortcuts import render

        # Create your views here.
        from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
        from django.urls import reverse

        from .models import BlogPost
        from .forms import BlogPostForm

        def index(request):
            """The home page for Road Ahead project."""
            return render(request, 'blog/index.html')

        def blogposts(request):
            """Show all blogposts (in reverse order)."""
            blogposts = BlogPost.objects.order_by('-date_added')
            context = {'blogposts': blogposts}
            return render(request, 'blog/blogposts.html', context)

        def topic(request, topic_id):
            """Show a single post and all its entries."""
            topic = BlogPost.objects.get(id=topic_id)
            entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('date_added')
            context = {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries}
            return render(request, 'blog/topic.html', context)

        def new_topic(request):
            """Add a new topic."""
            if request.method != 'POST':
                # No data submitted; create a new blank form.
                form = BlogPostForm()
            else:
                # Post data submitted; process data.
                form = BlogPostForm(data=request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                    form.save()
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blog:blogposts'))

            context = {'form': form}
            return render(request, 'blog/new_topic.html', context)

    ````

    {% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

    {% block content %}

      <p>Topic: {{ topic }}</p>

      <p>Entries:</p>

      <ul>
      {% for entry in entries %}
        <li>
          <p>{{ entry.date_added|date:'M d, Y H:i' }}</p>
          <p>{{ entry.text|linebreaks }}</p>
        </li>
      {% empty %}
        <li>
          There are no entries for this post yet.
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
      </ul>

    {% endblock content %}
`````

Besides the index and base=parent html pages, I have 3 other pages all copied above: blogposts, which lists all bulleted blog topics, topic, which displays topic name and entries, new_topic, which is supposed to allow user topic entry. New_topic appears to be the issue here-I can enter a new topic, and I've not gotten any error messages to troubleshoot, but all I get are bullet points, no topic name. Again it's possible to add topics and content on the back end; not what I want though. Thanks

Comment: There's not nearly enough information here. What is the relationship between those two templates? More importantly, where are the relevant views?

Comment: fyi - turns out my forms.py was missing an attribute 'title' that was on my models.py. Once added, the issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

What is your question, exactly?

Because as it stands, it looks like you're just trying to get us to do your programming for you.

Comment: I don't know how to get the topic names to show up beside the bullet points; worked with the initial topic set up, but not with adding new topics by user; sorry, just beginning at this.